# High-performance way to eliminate semi-duplicate items from a list

Tags: python, performance, data-structures, loops

I have a series of puzzles: Strings of morse code with no spaces between the letters or words.  My plan is to do a dictionary attack to find the best solution candidates. My weapon is Python.

I have a list of 17000 English words. I also have a much smaller list of words that are pertinent to the puzzle's theme, and if those words show up they should score higher.

So at the very beginning of my script when I generate the list of words, I use a list of tuples of the form (word, scoremultiplier). Here's a small subset:

```
[('zoned', 1.0), 
 ('zonely', 1.0), 
 ('zoner', 1.0), 
 ('zones', 1.0), 
 ('zoning', 1.0), 
 ('zoo', 1.0), 
 ('zoom', 1.0), 
 ('zoomed', 1.0), 
 ('zooming', 1.0), 
 ('zooms', 1.0), 
 ('zoos', 1.0), 
 ('ten', 1.0), 
 ('tens', 1.0), 
 ('gnash', 1.0), 
 ('shag', 1.0), 
 ('75th', 2.0), 
 ('seventy', 2.0), 
 ('fifth', 2.0)]
```

In the file that I parse all that out of, I want to just stick the high-value words at the end, without manually getting rid of any duplicates in the main part of the file. So I need to write something to get rid of the early tuples whose first value is equal to that of a later tuple.

I can do this with brute force:

```
for firstkey, (firstword, firstfactor) in enumerate(wordlist):
    for laterkey, (laterword, laterfactor) in enumerate(wordlist[firstkey+1:]):
        if firstword == laterword:
            del wordlist[firstkey]
            break
```

But that part of the script alone takes almost 45 seconds, and my 17000 words isn't even a full dictionary. (That code is also untested other than the time it takes to finish, so it may not even work.) It also seems very un-Pythony, though I'm just now learning Python (and doing some of my first programming at all) with this very project.

Is there a better way to do this? I can't use `set()` because the duplicate words are part of nonequal tuples. Do I need to restructure my data somehow? Or should I just be prepared to wait a full minute every time I run this?

Comment: If you can use ==, you should be able to use a `set`. What do you mean by "the duplicate words are not 100% duplicates"?

Comment: I clarified that sentence; the duplicate words are members of nonequal tuples. So if I use `set()`, both words will still be present.

Comment: Cool problem please could you share a link with us?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I might be misunderstanding the question, but it looks like you can generate a `dict` from the list of tuples. Later values will automatically overwrite earlier ones:

```
lst = [
    ('foo', 1),
    ('bar', 2),
    ('foo', 10)
]

print dict(lst) # {'foo': 10, 'bar': 2}
```

Comment: thats cool but this way he wont keep the higher values, just the last ones

Comment: I'm actually okay with that. "Last declared value" is not inferior to "Highest declared value" in my particular case. I would like the option to do it either way, but if that answer doesn't turn up, this will definitely suffice for my circumstances.

Comment: I think using a dictionary makes sense even if you want the highest value. You won't be able to simply pass the list of tuples to the dict constructor, but a simple loop will work: `for key, value in lst: if value > dct.get(key, 0): dict[key] = value`. Using a dict makes accessing the previous value (if it exists) fast. A `defaultdict` from the `collections` would also work, eliminating the need to use `dict.get`.

Comment: Yeah, my first thought was `max_scores = defaultdict(int)` / `for word, word_score in word_scores: max_scores[word] = max(max_scores[word], word_score)`.

Comment: Yeah, I'm realizing the more I think about it that using tuples was the wrong way to go. Using a dictionary *feels* wrong; the main thing I'm interested in is the keys, not the values. But dictionaries seem to be the practical thing to do.